# How to add a docID from one NotesDocument to another using Java Script

Tags: java, javascript, xpages, lotus-notes

I have a lotus script that add a organization docID to the contactDoc and it work fine but I would like achieve this in java script

```
Sub AddContactID(contact As NotesDocument, organisation As NotesDocument)
contact.TmpIDString =  organisation.DocID(0)    
Dim tmp As Variant
tmp = |@SetField("ContactOrganisationIDs";@Trim(@Unique(ContactOrganisationIDs:TmpIDString)))|
Dim flag As Variant
flag = Evaluate(tmp,contact)

Dim Item As NotesItem
Set Item = contact.GetFirstItem("TmpIDString")
If Not (Item Is Nothing) Then
    Call Item.Remove
End If
End Sub
```

Reverse Function:

```
Sub RemoveOrganisationIDByID(contactDocId As String, organisation As NotesDocument)

Dim Session As New NotesSession
Dim CurrDb As NotesDatabase
Set CurrDb = Session.CurrentDatabase
Dim contact As NotesDocument
Set contact = CurrDb.GetDocumentByUNID(contactDocId)
If contact Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If organisation Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim ContactOrganisationIDs As Variant
ContactOrganisationIDs = contact.ContactOrganisationIDs
pos = ArrayGetIndex(ContactOrganisationIDs, organisation.DocID(0))
If Not IsNull(pos) Then
    ContactOrganisationIDs(pos) = ""
    Call contact.ReplaceItemValue("ContactOrganisationIDs",FullTrim(ContactOrganisationIDs))
    Call contact.Save(True, False)
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SSJS function should do it

```
function addContactID(contact, organisation) {
    contact.replaceItemValue("TmpIDString", organisation.getItemValueString("DocID"));
    session.evaluate('FIELD ContactOrganisationIDs := @Trim(@Unique(ContactOrganisationIDs:TmpIDString)); FIELD TmpIDString := @DeleteField; ""', contact);
}
```

Parameters `contact` and `organisation` have to be of type `NotesDocument`. Don't forget to save the contact document sometime after calling the function.

Comment: Every time i run my addContactID() a new contact is added to the organisation but i want the old to be replace by the new  one, so that i could have one contact id at a time, so i created new function that could remove the old one

Comment: function removeContactIDByID(contactDocId, organisation) {
 var  CurrDb = session.getCurrentDatabase()
 var contact = CurrDb.getDocumentByUNID(contactDocId)
 if(contact== null){return }
 if(organisation == null){return }
 var ContactOrganisationIDs = contact.getItemValue("ContactOrganisationIDs")
 var pos =ContactOrganisationIDs.indexOf(organisation.getItemvalueString("DocID"))

 if(pos !=null){
  ContactOrganisationIDs.elementAt(pos) = ""
   contact.ReplaceItemValue("ContactOrganisationIDs",@FullTrim(ContactOrganisationIDs))
   contact.save()
 }
 
}

Comment: but it not removing the old one ID i keep getting Exception error

Comment: My function above does exactly what you did with your LotusScript function. It adds the organisation id to the ContactOrganisationIDs list in contact document. If you want just one organisation id in ContactOrganisationIDs then replace the function content with just `contact.replaceItemValue("ContactOrganisationIDs", organisation.getItemValueString("DocID"));`.

Comment: yes that work fine and i want to do the function that remove the organisation id from the ContactOrganisationIDs list as well

Comment: Ok, then use this "opposite" function:               `function removeContactID(contact, organisation) { contact.replaceItemValue("TmpIDString", organisation.getItemValueString("DocID")); session.evaluate('FIELD ContactOrganisationIDs := @Trim(@Replace(ContactOrganisationIDs; TmpIDString; "")); FIELD TmpIDString := @DeleteField; ""', contact); } `

Comment: Hello Sir, i try the oppsite function but it did not work but i want u to take a look am my reverse function in lutus script:

Comment: Use this function in addition to the first reverse function: `function removeContactIDByID(contactDocId, organisation) { 
 var CurrDb = session.getCurrentDatabase();
 var contact = CurrDb.getDocumentByUNID(contactDocId);
 if (contact != null && organisation != null) {
  removeContactID(contact, organisation);
  contact.save();
 }
}`